# jQuery on click scroll and open a tab

Tags: jquery

I have on a page 4 tabs and they all have ids (specs,info,about,reviews). On the top of the page I have a link `reviews`. what I want I guess is simple but no way I cannot make it work.
 When I click on the `reviews` link the page will scroll and open the 4th tab that has the content of the reviews.
The 'reviews' href is inside a div called `reviews-container` and the id of the reviews tab is `tab-reviews`

I have tried this:

```
jQuery('.reviews-container > a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); jQuery('#tab-reviews > a').click(); }); <br>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: what is the error u r getting in console. post it here if any .. have you tried removing that angle brackets in the selector

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML code too? How exactly that <a> tag defined and so on..

Comment: Are you using `jquery UI Accordion ` http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: hello, no i am using magento easy tabs.sure they must be based on jquery. There are not any error messages in the console. i see that the tab get's clicked with '<a href="javascript:void(0)"> so maybe this will be a problem?i thought it will be easy with jQuery to emulate another click on a page after you click something. maybe the JS should go to the file that is rendering the tabs. i will try to paste some of the code although i am not sure that it will help and it's also lot of complex.thank you